# doctrine query builder failing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have the following doctrine query builer that returns me with this error:

```
No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.
```

I suspect that the error comes because it can't find one of the associations since not all the fields have that association.
Where i believe is the problem:

```
->join('b.answer', 'c')
```

The method:

```
  public function getOneByStep($step, $surveyId)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        return $qb
            ->select(['u', 'b', 'c'])
            ->from(QuestionManager::class, 'u')
            ->join('u.survey', 'a')
            ->join('u.suggestQuestionManager', 'b')
            ->join('b.answer', 'c')
            ->where('u.step = :step')
            ->andWhere('a.id = :survey')
            ->setParameter('step', $step)
            ->setParameter('survey', $surveyId)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult()
            ;
    }
```

Comment: leftJoin('b.answer','answer') Probably want to use left join for pretty much any join by default.

Comment: can you post it as answer so i can accept it ? :D

Answer (score 1):

The given query does not return any result for the data in the database. This should ideally be handled using `NoResultException`.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

public function getOneByStep($step, $surveyId)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        ->select(['u', 'b', 'c'])
        ->from(QuestionManager::class, 'u')
        ->join('u.survey', 'a')
        ->join('u.suggestQuestionManager', 'b')
        ->join('b.answer', 'c')
        ->where('u.step = :step')
        ->andWhere('a.id = :survey')
        ->setParameter('step', $step)
        ->setParameter('survey', $surveyId);

    try {
        return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: my problem is that the record exists in the database. the problem was that doctrine couldn't find it since b.answer it will not always return a record.

Comment: Yes, and this lead to `getSingleResult()` not returning any results which cased the error. See https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L806 and https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/c1943624ab1260c629316bab104dc5130c060154/lib/Doctrine/ORM/NoResultException.php#L35